# Issue with SqlParameter and data type

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am just calling a stored procedure which was developed with SQL Server 2005.
Here is the signature of my stored proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenericSearch]
(
@ModuleName VARCHAR(100),
@ViewName VARCHAR(100),
@WhereClause_XML XML,
@LogicalOperator VARCHAR(3)
)
AS
BEGIN

END
```

I just call this stored procedure from my front end and pass value like

```
string[] Tables = new string[] { "TPMaster" };
SqlParameter[] cparams = new SqlParameter[4];
SqlParameter param;
param = new SqlParameter("@ModuleName", ModuleName);
param.DbType = DbType.String;
cparams[0] = param;

param = new SqlParameter("@ViewName", DataSource);
param.DbType = DbType.String;
cparams[1] = param;

param = new SqlParameter("@WhereClause_XML", strXml);
param.DbType = DbType.Xml;
cparams[2] = param;

param = new SqlParameter("@LogicalOperator", (rbAnd.Checked ? "AND" : "OR"));
param.DbType = DbType.String;
cparams[3] = param;

ds = Business.Common.GetDataSet("GenericSearch", cparams, Tables);
```

Here I specify that `param.DbType` string for all my `varchar` datatype for stored proc and one xml data type.

I am getting an error

> Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type
>   'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

I just do not understand what causes the error. Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Hmm seems very strange, I would double check that your app is definitely pointing at the correct proc, or even the correct DB. Try dropping the proc does your app then moan its not there?

Comment: where does `@statement` come from?

Comment: @statement is the first argument of the stored procedure sp_executesql.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using sp_executesql, and not passing the correct type of argument.  @statement is the required argument for sp_executesql and has to be a unicode constant or unicode variable.  I'm assuming your building a sql statement based upon the values your accepting into your stored proc.

Consider this example:

```
DECLARE @FieldName VARCHAR(100),@TableName VARCHAR(100),@WhereClause varchar(100)

SET @FieldName = 'ItemID'
SET @TableName = 'Item'
SET @WhereClause = 'ItemID > 200' 

DECLARE @yourSql varchar(max)

SET @yourSql = 'SELECT ' + @FieldName + ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @WhereClause

EXEC sp_executesql @yourSql
```

This should throw the same exception your getting.  However, change the declaration of the variable @yourSql from a varchar to an nvarchar like this:

```
DECLARE @yourSql nvarchar(max)
```

And you're in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

Check the body of the stored procedure, and the internal calls it makes.

Probably you're making a call to `sp_executesql` and are passing a simple `varchar` as the body of the SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DbType.AnsiString` for `VARCHAR` and `DbType.String` for `NVARCHAR`.

Here is a code snippet that I used in a O/R-mapper:

```
switch (systemType) {
    case 127: // bigint
        return DbType.Int64;
    case 173: // binary
    case 189: // timestamp
    case 165: // varbinary, varbinary MAX
    case 34: // image
        return DbType.Binary;
    case 98: // sql_variant
        return DbType.Object;
    case 104: // bit
        return DbType.Boolean;
    case 175: // char
        return DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength;
    case 61: // datetime
    case 58: // smalldatetime
        return DbType.DateTime;
    case 106: // decimal
    case 108: // numeric
        return DbType.Decimal;
    case 62: // float
        return DbType.Double;
    case 56: // int
        return DbType.Int32;
    case 60: // money
    case 122: // smallmoney
        return DbType.Currency;
    case 239: // nchar
        return DbType.StringFixedLength;
    case 99: // ntext
    case 231: // nvarchar, nvarchar MAX
        return DbType.String;
    case 59: // real
        return DbType.Single;
    case 52: // smallint
        return DbType.Int16;
    case 35: // text
    case 167: // varchar, varchar MAX
        return DbType.AnsiString;
    case 48: // tinyint
        return DbType.Byte;
    case 36: // uniqueidentifier
        return DbType.Guid;
    case 241: // xml
        return DbType.Xml;
    default:
        return (DbType)(-1);
}
```